# nestled resources and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a form inside of a project view which allows a user to give money to that project. I have set up nestled resources to associate each payment with the appropriate project. I am having trouble with submitting the form to the correct path. In routes.rb I have this:

```
 resources :projects do
    resources :payments, only: [:new, :create, :show]
end
```

the form looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row Row one">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
         <%= form_for [@projects, @payments] , method: 'post' do %>

                <%= label_tag("First Name") %><br>
                <%= text_field(:user, :first_name, class: 'form-control', :required => true) %><br>

                <%= label_tag("Last Name") %><br>
                <%= text_field(:user, :last_name, class: 'form-control', :required => true) %><br>

                <%= label_tag("Card Number") %><br>
                <%= text_field(:user, :cc_num, class: 'form-control', :required => true)%><br>

                <%= label_tag("Expiration Month") %><br>
                <%= text_field(:user, :exp_month, class: 'form-control', :required => true)%>   

                <%= label_tag("Expiration Year") %><br>
                <%= text_field(:user, :exp_year, class: 'form-control', :required => true)%>    

                <%= label_tag("Amount") %><br>
                <%= text_field(:user, :amount, class: 'form-control', :required => true)%> 

                <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, :value => current_user.id , class: 'form-control'%>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :project_id, :value => @project.id , class: 'form-control'%>

                <%= submit_tag("Sign Up") %>
                <% end %> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="row"></div> -->
```

I have tried wrapping the array in parentheses, and I have also tried:

```
<% form_for @projects, :url => {:action => 'create', :id => @project.id }, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>
```

as I have seen suggested in other threads but that is not working for me. Rake routes shows the path should be:

```
project_payments POST   /projects/:project_id/payments(.:format)     payments#create
```

the error I get is:

```
No route matches [POST] "/projects/1"
```

How should I be routing this form? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the head of the form needed to be more explicit in my case:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @payment], url: project_payments_path(@project.id) , method: 'post' do %>
```